# Parsing Table doesn't get all td elements

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am parsing an HTML table using `C#` and `HTMLAgilityPack` and not all the `td` elements are being returned for each row. It gets the first and 3rd and 4th, but misses the 2nd one.

I have looped through the code, but cannot understand where I am going wrong.

HTML:

```
<tr>
  <td>08:15</td>
  <td>EZY891</td>
  <td>London Gatwick</td>
  <td>Cancelled</td>
  <td><img class="bt_tweet_img" src="~/_Layouts/15/images/C5.PortOfJersey/content/Twitter_Logo_Blue.svg"alt="2019/09/02 08:15 GMT+00:00|EZY891"></td>
</tr>
```

CODE c#

```
//set the url we are interested in
string urlstring = 
"http://www.jerseyairport.com/flight/Pages/arrivals.aspx";
//use HTML Agilitypack to do the rest
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument document = web.Load(urlstring);      

foreach (HtmlNode flightdiv in 
document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@id='airport" + "arrivals" 
+ "']/tbody//tr"))

{
 foreach (HtmlNode col in flightdiv.SelectNodes("td"))

            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(col.InnerText);

            }
}
```

I am expecting to loop through each element, but it goes straight from the 08:15 to London Gatwick missing EZY891

Comment: The website does not have a column for `<td>EZY891</td>`. Where have you got that information from?

Comment: Your URL is wrong, use `https://www.jerseyairport.com/Flight/Pages/Arrivals.aspx`. If you use the one you have here, it will redirect you to a different page with fewer columns.

Comment: Apologies, I must be missing something. I am using the site https://www.jerseyairport.com/Flight/Pages/Arrivals.aspx. It has 4 columns Sched./Flight No./Origin/Status. It returns  Sched./Origin/Status. i.e. it misses the second one, Flight No.

Answer (score 0):

I have just checked the website, there is no second column in that table, so your code is working correctly

Your updated URL is still forwarding to https://www.jerseyairport.com/Pages/Default.aspx
Which doesn't have the flight number

Comment: Sorry, but it has 4 columns. Why can't I get the second column.?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason of using HTMLAgilityPack?

I let you a working code with the Selenium library. I used this 2 libraries "OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome" and "OpenQA.Selenium" just make sure the version for your Chrome is a compatible one.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var options = new ChromeOptions();           
    options.BinaryLocation = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\chrome.exe";
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);           
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.jerseyairport.com/flight/Pages/arrivals.aspx");

    IWebElement table = driver.FindElementById("airportarrivals");
    IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> tdElements = table.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
    foreach(IWebElement webElement in tdElements)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(webElement.GetAttribute("innerText"));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
08:15
London Gatwick
Cancelled

13:10
Southampton
Landed at 13:16

13:10
London Gatwick
Landed at 13:25

13:10
London Gatwick
Landed at 13:25

13:25
Birmingham
Landed at 13:11
```

Comment: Is there any benefit in using Selenium over HTMLAgilityPack.? Also, your code is still only delivering back 3 columns. It misses the flight number.

Comment: Sorry you are right, I copied the first URL instead of the second. Change de URL for "https://www.jerseyairport.com/Flight/Pages/Arrivals.aspx" and you will get also the Flight No.

Selenium can be slower if you need to collect a huge amount of information (around 200 elements looping on the as WebElements one by one). However, in my opinion, it is more friendly than HTMLAgilityPack and this problem can be solved working first with the Attributes as string and then looking for the correct IWebElement.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers supplied. The answer was quite simple. I was using http://www.jerseyairport.com/flight/Pages/arrivals.aspx in the web address rather than https://www.jerseyairport.com/flight/Pages/arrivals.aspx.
As soon as I corrected that it worked fine.
Thanks again